# How can I save a list of classes in a file? Can I display certain classes of a list through console?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say there's a class "Employee". It has Name (string) and Description (string).

I made a list called "Employees" which supposed to contain different "Employee" classes with different parameters.

I've tried displaying it with foreach operator, however, it returns only ".Employee" string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Work
{
    // Employee class
    public class Employee
    {
        public int ID;
        public string Name;
        public string Description;
    }

    class Program
    {

        // Create a list
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        // Add new employye method
        private void CreateEmployee(int id, string name, string description)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.ID = id;
            employee.Name = name;
            employee.Description = description;

            employees.Add(employee);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Neccessary because void Main() is static field
            Program P = new Program();
            // Calling method and adding new employee with new parameters to the list
            P.CreateEmployee(1, "James", "Funny");

            // Now's the question:
            // How to access this data?
            // I would like to make a file which would contain all information in the list, which I can read and load in a list again
            // Or just at least display it to the console
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I want a file that would be like:

```
1,"James","Funny";
2,"John","Just John";
```

Though, I'm not sure that **""** are necessary for saving strings.

Comment: Is it necessary to save it in a file? What about creating a database and storing employee info there? If it has to be a file, are you wanting to create a csv or plain text, etc.?

Comment: Overload the `ToString` funciton in your `Employee` class and use that.

Comment: Ryan Wilson, that's an option as well, though I'm afraid it requires pre-installed programs to run it on a PC? I'm looking forward to creating a program that can be installed on any other PC

Comment: Maybe this will help someone. ```Console.WriteLine("{0}", employees.Select(e => e.ToString()).ToArray());``` displays first element (class) of the list: "1, James, Funny" ```Console.WriteLine("{1}", employees.Select(e => e.ToString()).ToArray());``` displays second one: "2, John, Just John"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firsly, why you are creating instance of `Program` class, just make method as well as the list `static` and use them directly in `Main` method.

Secondly, why you created method `CreateEmployee`? Just define constructor for your `Employee` class, which will do the work of assigning values to fields.

Finally, what you looking for is string representation of your object of type `Employee`. Overriding `ToString` method is the key here.

So your class should look like:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public string Description;

    public Employee(int ID, string Name, string Description)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Description = Description;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{ID}, {Name}, {Description}";
    }
}
```

Having this, you could write your `Main` method like this:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
employees.Add(new Employee(1, "James", "Funny"));
File.WriteAllLines("file path", employees.Select(e => e.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that really helped me. I was looking exactly for THIS solution, that's awesome. You're missing one round bracket in the last line and also I think we should mention that this requires ```using System.Linq;``` Though it works, I'm going to check the documentation because of some aspects of the code a little bit confusing, but I hope I'll understand after some research. Thanks, you helped me make a little breakthrough

Comment: @Ethan It's normal for `using` statements to be omitted, particularly when framework namespaces are involved.

Comment: Could you please tell how to load data from a file to the list?

Comment: @Ethan `File.ReadAllLines` is what you need. I also recommend reading about `File` class and exploring it's static methods for reading and writeing to file.

Comment: So, how do I convert a line from a file to Employee type? I tried ```List<Employee> employees = File.ReadAllLines("d:\\employees.txt").ToList();``` and it says it cannot implicitly convert type ...<string>... to ...<Work.Employee>

Comment: @Ethan `File.ReadAllLines("d:\\employees.txt").Select(l => l.Split(",").Select(i => i.Trim())).Select( l => new Employee(int.Parse(l[0]), l[1], l[2])).ToList();`

Comment: For some reason, I can't get it working. It keeps saying that "Employee does not contain a constructor that takes that many arguments", "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'", "ToList does not exist in the current context"... Why is it? Though I start to understand how it works

Comment: Now it says only "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IEnumerable<string>" three times

Comment: @Ethan Try `File.ReadAllLines("d:\\employees.txt").Select(l => l.Split(",").Select(i => i.Trim()).ToArray()).Select( l => new Employee(int.Parse(l[0]), l[1], l[2])).ToList();`

Comment: This one is working. So it was because we needed to make an array out of the data before loading it, I suppose